# angular2-multiselect:display selected values in list while editing module

Tags: angular, multi-select

I am using `angular2-multiselect-dropdown` for multiple dropdown in angular4. It's working perfect while creating the records, but not working fine during updation.

All previously selected values should be checked, and not able to select twice. but here it's not already selected and one can select same value again.

attaching screenshot, please let me know what can i do. will update my code if required.

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've experienced the same problem with ng-select. Here is a link with entire explanation how to update options in multiselect box after creating new option. Hope it helps. `https://basvandenberg.github.io/ng-select#/examples/intro`

Comment: You should post your implementation code (`.html`, `.ts`)

Comment: I got the solution, the data while creating list having id value as string, and data on editing is having id value as integer. that was the actual difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution, Posting here as answer so that no one finds the same issue.
It was a tiny change that makes me crazy for hours.
Here is the solution, the main difference was id for edit is string and for create is integer. After making it similar problem is resolved. Angular2-multiselct is really awesome.

> DataList on Edit:

```
[{id: "1", itemName: "Text1", value: "1"},
{id: "2", itemName: "Text2", value: "2"},
{id: "3", itemName: "Text3", value: "3"}]
```

> DataList on Create:

```
[{id:1, itemName: "Text1", value: "1"},
{id:2, itemName: "Text2", value: "2"},
{id:3, itemName: "Text3", value: "3"},
{id:4, itemName: "Text4", value: "4"},
{id:5, itemName: "Text5", value: "5"}]
```

Comment: This particular question and answer saved me after days of stressing myself on using patchValue with ngMultiSelect dropdown.  Many thanks to you.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using angular forms, like formgroup, then you can use `setValue()` method to set the value.
Please refer angualr forms.

Example:

```
this.form-name.setValue({
    dropdown : some-value
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `patchValue()` method under FormBuilder to set single control in the form like

```
this.formGroup.patchValue({
control-name:value
})

this.form.controls['control-name'].patchValue(value)
```

**NOTE:** Works with specific control only